# Изменение пути установки скриптов

Tags: python, pip

Как изменить путь установки скриптов. Пишу например:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Скрипты устанавливаются в C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts, а хотелось бы C:\Program Files\Python\Python39\Scripts сюда

Comment: надо было устанавливать питон для всех пользователей в системную папку, а не для одного единственного в пользовательскую. Попробуй запустить пип из под администратора

Comment: при установки стояла галочка install for all users

Comment: значит нужно пип запускать администратором, потому что у простого пользователя нет прав записи в програмфайлс

Comment: у меня с админскими правами пользователь, я так понимаю нужно в конфиге pip место установки переназначить

Comment: вы можете попробовать поискать как установить в конфиге место установки, а можете просто запустить командную строку как администратор и проверить без лишних телодвижений

Comment: я от имени администратора пробовал

Comment: Ну не знаю, я запускаю от администратора и у меня ставится как раз  туда, куда вам хочется. Без всяких правок конфигов.